# Eclipselink group by clause with trunc function

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, jpql

I have a query which works in sqldeveloper, but not in jpql (eclipselink 2.6).

```
select trunc(SYS_CR_DT, 'mm'), count(trunc(SYS_CR_DT, 'mm')) from A
group by trunc(SYS_CR_DT, 'mm')
order by trunc(SYS_CR_DT, 'mm') DESC;
```

This works in sqldeveloper, but this is not(in jpql), saying it is not a group by expression :

```
"SELECT FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate, 'mm'), COUNT(FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate, 'mm')) "
        + " FROM A lh"
        + " GROUP BY FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate, 'mm')"
        + " ORDER BY FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate, 'mm') DESC";
```

This also works, so grouping with that function is working :

```
"SELECT FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate), COUNT(FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate)) "
        + " FROM A lh"
        + " GROUP BY FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate)"
        + " ORDER BY FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate) DESC";
```

This works also, so it is not a problem with the second parameter, but with the grouping:

```
"SELECT FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate, 'mm'), COUNT(FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate, 'mm')) "
        + " FROM A lh"
```

Long story short : When I add the second parameter, it is still a valid function call, but not working inside group by.

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: "SELECT FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate, 'mm'), COUNT(FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate, 'mm')) "
        + " FROM A lh"
        + " GROUP BY FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate, 'mm')"
        + " ORDER BY FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate, 'mm')DESC";

Not working like that either, I just put alias in the end when i was trying different things, without alias the same problem exist. Works with 1 parameter, not working with true. Works with two parameter without grouping, works with one with grouping

Comment: your question should define the difference between 'works' and 'not working' - is there an exception, wrong results etc.  Chances are the JPQL parser are validating the JPQL and can't determine that the functions are operating on the same clause, in which case, just just use a native query instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I could not resolve the problem, seems like a bug for me.
Anyway, I made it work. Not a nice solution, but what can I do.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TRUNCBYMONTH(
    dateparam DATE
)
RETURN DATE
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN TRUNC(dateparam, 'mm');

END;
```

Calling this function instead of the original TRUNC with 'mm' extra parameter works correctly.

Comment: Do it like this way...SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM order_date) "Month"   FROM orders;

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL Developer query, you are grouping by `trunc(SYS_CR_DT, 'mm')`, where as in your `jpql` query you are grouping by `month`. So, really, those are not the same query, and comparing them is unfair.

The problem is that, in Oracle, aliases defined in a `select` clause (i.e.: `month`) cannot be referred to inside a `group by` clause.  The reason is simple: the `group by` clause gets processed *before* the `select` clause. (Using an alias in the `order by` clause is ok, because the `order by` clause gets processed last)

I'm no `jpql` expert, but I guess you'll need to do something like:

```
"SELECT FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate, 'mm') AS month, COUNT(FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate, 'mm')) "
        + " FROM A lh"
        + " GROUP BY FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate, 'mm')"
        + " ORDER BY month DESC";
```

Comment: Yes, Alias was a mistake to post, not working without it either. 
I just tried alias in the end, and I cant find here to edit my question.

Problem stays: with one parameter (without mm, and alias, but with group by), it is working. With two params, not

Comment: It doesn't help that you never provided the actual error message(s) either. For that reason, I answered based on what obviously could not work.

Comment: Is that with the alias or without?  Using the alias would definitely give you that error.  But using the function may give a different error. Like I said, I'm not JPQL expert.  But is there any way for you to see the actual SQL it gets translated to?  That would be most useful in debugging what is wrong.

Comment: Without, I just removed alias. The same problem existed before aliases.

  builder.append("SELECT FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate, 'mm'), COUNT(FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate, 'mm')) "
  + " FROM A lh"
  + " GROUP BY FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate, 'mm')"
  + " ORDER BY FUNCTION('TRUNC', lh.sysCreateDate, 'mm') DESC"); -> not working. Removing the 'mm' it is working, grouping by day

Comment: Edited my original question, removing the aliases. It was never wanted to be posted